# Regex based evaluations of given string

Tags: java, regex

I generate a 6 characters long random number. It can be all numeric, alphabets and alphanumeric. I have to validate this string on basis of provided regular expression. For example:

If string is numeric `[0-9]`, then it should not contain all zeroes.

If string is alphabetic `[a-zA-Z]`, then last character cannot be `X` or `x`. And string cannot start with `SVC` or `svc`.

If string is alphanumeric `[0-9a-zA-Z]`, then it cannot contain all zeroes `0`. And string cannot start with tripple zeroes `000` and cannot end with `x` or `X`.

I need regular expressions for these that can be used with Java `Matcher`.

Comment: The first of the two condions for the alphanumeric case is redundant. If the number does not start with `000`, then it is not all `0`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://regex101.com/r/NbwNzK/4) should work:

```
/^((?!.{7,})[0-9]*[1-9]+[0-9]*|(?!(SVC|svc))[a-zA-Z]{5}[a-wy-zA-WY-Z]|(?!(000|.{7,}))[0-9a-zA-Z]*([a-zA-Z][0-9]|[0-9][a-zA-Z])+[0-9a-zA-Z]*[a-wy-zA-WY-Z])$/gm
```

I cannot explain this regex, as it is too long and just a repetitive application of the same concepts over and over. However, given the following input, it matches only the first five lines:

```
002000
jfkasd
002dfd
sVcabc
abc65i
000000
00012c
0123ax
SVCabx
svcabc
abc65x
abc65X
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/NbwNzK/2)'s the original attempt I proposed, which does not satisfy all the condition of the OP, but it is accompained by an explanation:

```
/^((?!.{7,})[0-9]*[1-9]+[0-9]*|[a-zA-Z]{5}[a-wy-zA-WY-Z]|(?!000)[0-9a-zA-Z]{6})$/gm
```

Explanation (which could read on the linked page itself):

- We have three alternatives that have to match the whole line: `^(…|…|…)$`;
- The 2nd alernative is easy: five letters followed by one letter which is not `x` or `X`, `[a-zA-Z]{5}[a-wy-zA-WY-Z]` (`[^xX]` would match numers too or anything else).
- The 3rd alternative is slightly more complex: six letters or digits, which is not preceded by `000`; this uses a negative lookahead, and it works because of the anchor `^` (if you remove that, it breaks).
- The 1st alternative is similar: zero or more digits, followed by **one** or more non-0 digits, followed by zero or more digits; all not starting by 7 or more characters.

Comment: Thanks. Given URL is quite helpful to play with it. Furthermore, SVCabc
abc65X should be invalid as well for example.